# OpenVPN keeps flipping back VPN connections

Tags: networking, 16.04, vpn, openvpn

I installed PrivateInternetAccess VPN on my machine using the instructions provided [here](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn).

Now when I open the network settings, the dialog appears for me, but every time I click to turn "on" any VPN connection, it immediately flips back to "off".

[image]

What could be going wrong here? What would be a good way to debug this?

FWIW I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, GNOME.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a wrong user name.

It's surprising that neither PrivateInternetAccess nor OpenVPN have no feedback / error reporting mechanism.